# Why Can the Widget Receive Other Static Broadcasts When Only One Static Broadcast Is declared?

Tags: android, widget, broadcast

I only declare one action like `<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />`.
but my widget can receive android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED,android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED,android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED...
How did he do it?

Comment: That one works a little differently than you might expect. Basically, the manifest entry is only there to let the system know that you have an App Widget. After that, the broadcasts that it receives during runtime are explicitly targeting your Receiver, so that `<intent-filter>` is never actually used to match individual broadcasts.

Comment: but i see AppWidgetServiceImpl.java
when it Invok method **sendEnableIntentLocked(Provider p)**,  it use **sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, p.id.getProfile());**. As far as I know, broadcast is depending on **<intnet-filter>** I wish to know how can it "explicitly targeting my Receiver"

Comment: I don't know which specific version's source you're looking at, but there should be a `setComponent()` call, or something equivalent, before that `sendBroadcastAsUser()` call. That component is your Receiver, and having that component set on the broadcast `Intent` is what makes it explicit.